# Open text file to read line by line to get data before running bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I am currently working on a bash script which the content of the script will prompt user for directory path and i stored the directory path in a variable. Then, i copy the file in the directory path to my path, convert the file (.html) to (.xls). After that, i used mailx command to send the (.xls) file through email. However, the files could be more than 1 and it is not fix every week.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the path: (e.g. /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/system_name/24_july/full_file)"
read directory

systemname=$(echo $directory | cut -d'/' -f11) #-f11 indicates 'system_name"
dates=$(echo $directory | cut -d'/' -f12) #-f12 indicates '24_july'

cp $directory/mode1/consolidate_full_file/file.mode1/output_mode1/file.html .
mv file.html MODE1_NAME.xls

cp $directory/mode2/consolidate_full_file/file.mode2/output_mode2/file.html .
mv file.html MODE2_NAME.xls

echo "Sending files of $systemname on $dates" | mailx -s "Test" -a MODE1_NAME.xls -a MODE2_NAME.xls mmaz@hotmail.com
```

Therefore, i plan to ask user to create a text file, which contain the system_name, directory path, modes exist of the week. From that text file, i plan to open it from the bash script and take all the data needed. Is it possible to do that?

This is the example on the text file, blocka.txt:

```
systemname=blocka

directory=/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/system_name/24_july/full_file

List of modes:
MODE1_NAME= /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/system_name/24_july/full_file/mode1/consolidate_full_file/file.mode1/output_mode1/file.html
MODE2_NAME= /a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/system_name/24_july/full_file/mode2/consolidate_full_file/file.mode2/output_mode2/file.html

End of List of modes
```

I tried to find the string matching for systemname and directory, but how do i identify modes exist between List of modes: till End of List of modes.

From blocka.txt, i need to get the data required as variable so that i can reduce hardcoded in the bash script. Isthere any way so that i can try this way? because i am thinking it would be efficient enough as any systemname can use it by just makig changes on the text file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use `source`, which essentially runs the target file, keeping the variables set. However, this is insecure, allowing for people to insert whatever code they want into the file and have your main script run it.

Instead, we can run a `while` loop, reading the file line-by-line, and checking against a set of `if` statements.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    #If the current line starts with "systemname=", we assign systemname to the section after the equal sign
    if [[ $line =~ ^systemname= ]]; then systemname=$(echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'); fi
    if [[ $line =~ ^directory= ]]; then directory=$(echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'); fi
    #etc...

    #The MODEn_NAME section will take a bit more work, if we're expected to handle an unknown number of inputs.
    if [[ $line =~ ^MODE[0-9]*_NAME= ]]; then
        #The following extracts the number, and saves it to $index
        index=$(echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $1}' | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
        #Now we insert the text after the equal sign into an array element specified by the number
        modename[$index]=$(echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}')
        #We could have saved some code by simply adding to the next available index,
        #But then if a user entered the same mode number twice, we'd have a duplicate
    fi
done< "blocka.txt"

dates=$(echo $directory | cut -d'/' -f12) #-f12 indicates '24_july

#Since we have an unknown number of modename indexes (and not necessarily in order),
#we will use a for loop to go through them.
for i in "${!modename[*]}"; do 
    filelist="$filelist"" MODE""$i""_NAME.xls"#This will be used at the end
    #Edit: cp "$directory/mode""$i""/consolidate_full_file/file.mode""$i""/output_mode1/file.html" .
    #As far as I can tell, each MODEn_NAME entry contains the full directory of each file. Which means you really don't need the $directory from before.
    cp "$modename$i" .
    mv "file.html" "MODE""$i""_NAME.xls" #See note below
done
echo "Sending files of $systemname on $dates" | mailx -s "Test" -a "$filelist" mmaz@hotmail.com
```

For that move command at the end, you really don't need it; you could just copy to that name with the earlier `cp` command in the first place. But I included it to illustrate what I did, and didn't, change.